# How to show $\int_0^x\Big(\int_0^v[\int_0^u f(t) dt ]du \Big)dv=\dfrac 12 \int_0 ^x (x-t)^2f(t) dt$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

How to show that $\int_0^x\Big(\int_0^v[\int_0^u f(t) dt ]du \Big)dv=\dfrac 12 \int_0 ^x (x-t)^2f(t) dt$ ? I am completely at a loss ; the only vague idea I have is that I have to do a variable i.e. co-ordinate transformation but I don't know what . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: An instructive approach is to call $L(x)$ the left hand side, and $R(x)$ the right hand side. Then differentiate $L(x)$ and $R(x)$ twice, using the fundamental theorem of calculus, and show that the second derivatives are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a particular case of the "Cauchy's repeated integral" (Cauchy's formula).

Hint : The proof is easy by induction.

No need to copy out what is already written here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Change the order of integration so that the integral with respect to $x$ is the last one you calculate.

Comment: Could you please elaborate . I cannot understand :( . Thanks in advance